# What is this cable called?

Tags: usb, hardware, retropie

Does anyone know what this cable is called?

[image: Unknown cable]

I am using it to attach some arcade controls to my Raspberry Pi, but it broke and I need a replacement. I can't figure out what it is called so I can order a new one.

Comment: Do you have a larger picture of the white end? it looks like a header socket of some description but its too small to really make out what sort. The Electronic SE folk might be able to identify it if thats the only picture there is.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a [USB to serial cable](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/you-will-need).

Comment: @goobering I thought the same thing at first glance and I suppose in a sense it must be, but that (9 or 10 pin connector) implies it is intended for something more specific.  Dmitry seems to be correct that it's a "dupont header".  Presumably some motherboards use them?  Although this one  looks to have a 5th wire which to me implies a full FTDI type thing.

Answer (score 5):

This is a **USB pin header cable**. You can [order one on e-bay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/20cm-USB-2-0-Type-A-Male-to-Dupont-9-Pin-Female-Header-Motherboard-Cable-Cord-/281428514446?hash=item418672568e:g:xzYAAOSwnDZT~ajT) (though you'll probably want a longer one compared to what I have found), or salvage it from an old USB mouse or keyboard.

Measure the distance between the pins in the white connector. Usually, it's 2.54 mm (aka Dupont pin header), but it may be one of these:

[image]

In the latter case, it may be harder to buy a replacement, but googling for "USB pin header" together with the pin-to-pin distance should still work.

Comment: More specifically I guess this is a "Dupont 9 pin" connector used by some motherboards.

Comment: @goldilocks You have good eyes! Anyway, motherboard connectors typically have a female USB plug, and this is a male one. Might as well be an expensive variation of El-Cheapo generic mouse cable.

Comment: Actually what I was going to add is that pic looks like it has *10* holes...dunno if that matters.  The OP will have to have a look at whatever it is supposed to attach to anyway, hopefully there is enough info here to work that out.

Comment: @goldilocks Are you sure there are 10 holes? I added a pic to my post of what I guess it looks like. Of course, only the OP can tell for sure.

Comment: Yep.  Zoom in.  When I looked for "Dupont header" the first things I found were 9-pin, which are very similar but with one pin blocked out -- presumably to orient it correctly to a male jack with one pin missing.  But the one in the actual picture isn't that, it's got 10 holes.  Either it's the same thing and the guides on the jack body ensure it goes in right, or it is something else entirely.

Comment: @goldilocks did you again squander our precious RPi.SE funds ordering CSI to enhance the image?

Answer (score 2):

If the white plastic header didn't break, you can buy one that does NOT have the connector on the end, cut the wires from the old one near the end of the connector, leaving enough room, then solder and use heatshrink tubing over the cable to make it more robust....quick and easy.

Answer (score -3):

In Chrome browser: Right click on your picture and choose "Search Google for image" - it returns a lot of results regarding Joystick cables and arcade games

Comment: While this might be helpful, it doesn't really answer the question and might be better placed as a comment.